# How can i increase/decrease the explorer width of VsCode with shortcuts?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to increase or decrease the explorer panel width with shortcuts.
I tried to edit the shortcuts on settings with no results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What do you mean by "increase or decrease"? Its size? Please [edit] to clarify. And if you want more tips, check out [ask].

Comment: Do you mean like zoom in on it?

Comment: No, I mean the width.

Comment: Solution here: [Shortcut key for (controlling) increasing/decreasing current split panes width/height?](/q/43742604/4518341)

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks